# Let $H$ be subgroup of $G$, $a,b\in G$, how that $Ha=Hb$ iff $ab^{-1}\in H$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $H$ be subgroup of $G$, $a,b\in G$, how that $Ha=Hb$ iff $ab^{-1}\in H$.

Here $Ha$ denote the right coset. Please give me ideas of both direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose $\;1\in H\;$ , so

$$Ha=Hb\implies \;\exists\;h\in H\;\;s.t.\;\; a=1\cdot a=hb\implies ab^{-1}=h\in H$$

The other direction's idea:

$$ab^{-1}\in H\implies \;\exists\;h\in H\;\;s.t.\;\;ab^{-1}=h\in H\implies a=hb\in Hb\implies$$

$$\forall\;h'\in H\;,\;\;h'a=h'hb\in Hb\implies Ha\subset Hb$$

and since (right or left) costs of a subgroup in a group are in fact equivalence classes then either they're disjoint or else they're exactly the same set.

Comment: Did you consider $1$ as the identity element ?

Comment: @Abstraction Yes, of course.

Comment: Then why do you need to "choose" an identity element in $H$. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. So it always contain an identity element.

Comment: I don't "need": I **know** $\;H\;$ contains the group's identity and use that to show what we wanted, that's all.

Comment: Then "Choose $1\in H$, so" statement is actually not needed. That's what I want to convey. Anyways doesn't matter.

Comment: I really don't understand you: if $\;Ha=Hb\;$ , then this is true for **any** choice of element(s) in $\;H\;$ , and one such choice is $\;1\in H\;$ , which is what makes, imo, the above so easy.

Answer (score 1):

'$\implies$'

*Let $Ha=Hb$, let $p\in Ha$, so $p\in Hb$.*

*So, $p=h_1a$ and $p=h_2b$, $\implies h_1a=h_2 b \implies h_1ab^{-1}=h_2 \implies h_1(ab^{-1})=h_2$. Now RHS is in H. So LHS must be in H. So $h_1(ab^{-1})\in H\implies ab^{-1}\in H$*

'$\impliedby$'

*$ab^{-1}\in H$, so $H(ab^{-1})=H\implies H(ab^{-1})b=Hb \implies Ha=Hb. \blacksquare$*

$\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: “$p=ha$ and $p=hb$” is surely wrong; you probably mean “$p=h_1a$ and $p=h_2b$.

Comment: @egreg Why is it wrong ?

Comment: Because $p=ha$ and $p=hb$ implies $ha=hb$, so $h^{-1}ha=h^{-1}hb$, hence $a=b$. Of course we can have $Ha=Hb$ also for $a\ne b$.

Comment: @egreg, I corrected it !! Just have a look !!

Comment: @egreg, Thanks !!

Comment: No need to use $p$: you surely know $a\in Ha$, so just take $a$ instead of $p$.